# Snap is not executable after installation

Tags: snap

By using `sudo mount -t squashfs -o ro ./fingrom.snap ./tmp` I've been able to run the app inside. But in case of installing it from Discover, the button "Run" does nothing. How can it be resolved? Thanks in advance!

It's been generated from Flutter project by using `snapcraft`:

```
name: fingrom
base: core22
version: 1.0.0+1

grade: stable
confinement: strict

apps:
  fingrom:
    command: fingrom

parts:
  app-finance:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    build-packages: [libgtk-3-dev, ninja-build]
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart
```

[image]

```
$ snap run Fingrom
error: cannot find current revision for snap Fingrom: readlink /snap/Fingrom/current: no such file or directory
$ snap run fingrom
error: cannot find app "fingrom" in "fingrom"
```

Would appreciate your assistance.

---

**Update**
In `snapcraft.yaml` it's been missing:

```
apps:
  fingrom:
    command: fingrom
```

After adding that section the error is changed to: `error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Unclear since I can manually run it from its folder: /snap/fingrom/current/.

Comment: Why don't you use `sudo snap install <name>.snap --dangerous`?

Comment: @RA it has no difference. I can run app by clicking on it from /snap/fingrom/current/ but it's not recognizable from a terminal as it has to

Comment: I think you're confusing things a little. 1) don't just mount the snap as a squashfs file, that completely bypasses snap mediation. 2) Don't run the snap from `/snap/fingrom/current` as that also bypasses snap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing `libgtk-3.so.0` is because you have no `stage-packages` mentioned.  You'd need, at minimum:

```yaml
parts:
  app-finance:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    build-packages: [libgtk-3-dev, ninja-build]
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart
    stage-packages: [libgtk-3-0]
```

When you run the executable (see my comment above) the other ways, you're bypassing the snap confinement, and it likely finds the libgtk3 on your host.  You need to bundle the libraries your application needs inside the snap.

However, a better and easier option is to use the `gnome` extension.

```yaml
apps:
  fingrom:
    command: fingrom
    extensions: [gnome]
```

This is covered in the [documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/flutter-applications)